# Basic Postfix Setup Error

Tags: server, email, postfix

I am beginning with Linux and have found a basic installation guide for  [installing postfix in Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixBasicSetupHowto)

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

ran sudo apt-get -update

and sudo apt-get -upgrade

I get past the [Test your default setup](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixBasicSetupHowto#Test_your_default_setup) ok without any issues.

I go through [Setting Postfix Support for Maildir](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixBasicSetupHowto#Setting_Postfix_Support_for_Maildir-style_Mailboxes) at the end of it says "Check the mailbox of fmaster" I get "No mail for fmaster. - I guess that is correct.

My Main issue then arrives at [Adding your local domains](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixBasicSetupHowto#Adding_your_local_domains_to_postfix) when it says "Test your setup again using following code:" When I type in rcpt to: fmaster@euroglen.com or fmaster@localhost I get an error saying "Temporary lookup failure" if I reboot the computer I still get the same error.

I have deleted the Virtual Machine and started again now 3 times and have got the same error each time. I assume I have done nothing wrong ( 3 times) or have I? how can I attempt to continue?

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated     defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = Ubuntu
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mail.euroglen.com, localhost.localdomain, localhost, euroglen.com
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 1270.0.0.0/8 192.168.1.0/24
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/
mailbox_command =
```

output of "sudo cat /etc/aliases"

```
# See man 5 aliases for format
postmaster: root
```

Answer (score 1):

Run `newaliases` . If `/etc/aliases` doesn't exist then create it first, then run `newaliases` .
Also maybe update/add `alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases` to `/etc/postfix/main.cf` to get rid of the other warning.
Then try again.

If you test with telnet, you don't need working DNS.

Edit 1

This is my working main.cf from my working postfix

```
cat /etc/postfix/main.cf 
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = xxx.yyy.net
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = xxx.yyy.net, localhost.yyy.net, localhost
relayhost = smtp.yyy.net
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
```

I use `relayhost`. That means that all mail I send trough ISP smtp server.
You can copy/paste this config and change `myhostname`, `mydestination`, `relayhost` ...

Try

Comment: as in the question the main.cf file is displayed.

Comment: also give me output from command `sudo cat /etc/aliases`

Comment: You have one error `mynetworks = 1270.0.0.0/8 192.168.1.0/24`, change to `mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 192.168.1.0/24`

Comment: Now work your postfix?

Comment: output of the cat /etc/aliases added to the question for easy formatting. "now work your postfix?" still not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27342/discussion-between-2707974-and-john).

Comment: Do you reload postfix after changes?

Comment: Yes I did. sudo  /etc/init.d/postfix restart

Comment: I add my `main.cf` from working `postfix`.  Change some parameters and I hope will work.

Comment: no luck yet. I think i may format and try to find another how to?

Comment: maybe. try with another manual.